# mod_rewrite doing index incorrectly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite directives in a .htaccess file, so that URLs like http://example.com/foo/bar/baz are internally rewritten to index.php?page=baz

```
RewriteEngine     on
RewriteBase       /foo/bar/
RewriteRule       ^index.php          - [L,NC]
RewriteRule      ^([^/]*)/?$          index.php?&p=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule      ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  index.php?&p=$1&v=$2  [L,QSA]
```

It works fine at

- http://example.com/foo/bar/baz
- http://example.com/foo/bar/page/part
- http://example.com/foo/bar/foobar/baz

and anything else I've thrown at it, except if the first parameter is index.

- http://example.com/foo/bar/index and
- http://example.com/foo/bar/index/baz do not work.

I've turned RewriteLogLevel up to 9, and I get entries like this one when I visit  http://example.com/foo/bar/index/baz

```
[perdir ..../foo/bar/] add path info postfix: ..../foo/bar/index.php -> ..../foo/bar/index.php/baz
```

So it looks like something internal to apache is actually rewriting the /index/ part of the URL to /index.php/ before mod_rewrite even sees it, which is a bit of a problem. It isn't rewriting anything else incorrectly, just index.

I really don't understand why it won't work with index but will with everything else. These are the only rewrite directives for this project, and it's a stock setup otherwise.

This is Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.8.

---

I hope I'm being clear, but just in case, I want URLs rewritten like this:

- /foo/bar/index --> /foo/bar/index.php?page=index
- /foo/bar/index/ --> /foo/bar/index.php?page=index
- /foo/bar/page1 --> /foo/bar/index.php?page=page1
- /foo/bar/page2/word --> /foo/bar/index.php?page=page2&v=word

It all works fine, except for URLs with index.

Comment: try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your htaccess, to prevent the clash with `index.php`

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks! I guess that's some sort of content negotiation.

Comment: Yes it is, and Multiviews takes precedence over mod_rewrite, resulting in your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your htaccess, to prevent the clash with `index.php`